# Como mudar a cara do site quando acessado pelo celular?

Tags: html, css, mobile, template

Situação:

Tenho um site com designer para *large screens*, criei um template para mobile, tipo um aplicativo. Por isso quero que esse template seja mostrado apenas quando acessado pelo mobile, ao contrário mostre o convencional.

Como faço isso? Existe algum comando ou tag para isso no html ou no css?

Comment: Sua pergunta está vaga demais que podem gerar muitas respostas, você precisa especificar qual é seu ambiente de desenvolvimento, quais frameworks está usando e se possível uma página index como exemplo.

Comment: Estou usando HTML/CSS/JSCRIPT/ (estilo1.css)  no site desktop, no mobile quero usar um template adaptado (estilo2.css) . Apenas preciso saber como faço para quando acessar o site no computador eu usar o estilo1.css e quando acessar no celular eu usar o estilo2.css.

Answer (score 2):

Use as media queries do CSS.

O CSS Tricks tem um [repositório com as media queries](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) para as principais telas.

Exemplo de uso:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

  /** Formatar o menu para telas de iPhone 4 e 4s **/
  nav {
    color: white;
    background-color: #333333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }

}
```

Comment: @Mr.Iago, aconselho o uso de Media queries também, pois, o conceito de mobile ainda não foi totalmente definido, embora todos saibamos diferenciar. No caso, as mediaqueries são mais ágeis que uma verificação via javascript, e além disso, mais úteis em quesitos de estilização, já que é para isso que serve o CSS, podendo reutilizar as queries para estilizar outros elementos